# Python list comprehension for two values from the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I can find answers for using list comprehension with multiple values from multiple lists but I can not find a solution to my specific case where all elements (coordinates) in the list should be matched with all other elemets once. The nested for loop for the problem looks as follows:

```
# rr = list of coordinates (2D)
meet_critera = []

for idx1 in range(len(rr)-1):
    for idx2 in range(idx1+1, len(rr)):
        if coordinate_distance(rr[idx1], rr[idx2]) < 6000: # Could be any criteria
            meet_critera.append([rr[idx1], rr[idx2]])
print(meet_critera)
```

The loops are a classic "all should shake hands with each other once" problem if that helps. What I want is a more elegant way of producing the same result using list comprehension. If possible.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you encountered? Any nested loops + append can be directly translated to a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply write the loops in their order and the condition at the end.

```
meet_critera = [
    [rr[idx1], rr[idx2]]
    for idx1 in range(len(rr)-1)
    for idx2 in range(idx1+1, len(rr))
    if coordinate_distance(rr[idx1], rr[idx2]) < 6000
]

print(meet_critera)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I found in other threads but I must have made some typo becouse I could not get the ranges to work....

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.combinations`.

```
In [16]: from itertools import combinations

In [17]: rr = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

In [18]: list(combinations(rr, 2))
Out[18]:
[((0, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 2)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 2)),
 ((0, 1), (3, 4)),
 ((0, 1), (5, 6)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (0, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 4)),
 ((1, 1), (5, 6)),
 ((2, 1), (0, 2)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 2)),
 ((2, 1), (3, 4)),
 ((2, 1), (5, 6)),
 ((0, 2), (1, 2)),
 ((0, 2), (3, 4)),
 ((0, 2), (5, 6)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4)),
 ((1, 2), (5, 6)),
 ((3, 4), (5, 6))]
```

Of course, you don't have to convert it to a list if you just want to iterate over the items. And I'm assuming the order of the coordinates is not important here since you are calculating distance; if it is, use `permutations` instead.